# The query results enumerated more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

```
    datacontextclass dc=new datacontextclass ();
       var news= dc.GetNewsCompany(Int64.Parse ( _idCompany));
       if (news.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
       {
           foreach (var item in news)
           {
               drpListNews.Items.Add(item.Title);
           } 
       }
```

return error:{"The query results cannot be enumerated more than once."}

how can check result != null in LINQ;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an enumerator wildly is a bad idea - for example, it needs disposing - which you haven't done (this could lead to a `SqlDataReader` being left open - not good). In this case, *just enumerate it*. If there aren't any records, that will be trivial:

```
   if (news!=null)
   {
       foreach (var item in news)
       {
           drpListNews.Items.Add(item.Title);
       } 
   }
```

If you **need** the data twice, put it in a list:

```
   var news = (blah).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the enumerator twice. The first is by calling `news.GetEnumerator()`, the second one happens behind the scenes in the `foreach` loop. The first "check" that you make with the call to `MoveNext` does not seem necessary (you will not go into the `foreach` unless there are items to iterate over), so just skip the `if` statement wrapping the loop:

```
datacontextclass dc = new datacontextclass();
var news = dc.GetNewsCompany(Int64.Parse(_idCompany));
foreach (var item in news)
{
    drpListNews.Items.Add(item.Title);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the second line of your code to

```
    var news= dc.GetNewsCompany(Int64.Parse ( _idCompany)).toList();
```

it shall remove the issue.